# How to anchor to the bottom of the page while switching to the right video in a carousel?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a carousel at the bottom of my page with 3 youtube videos.
There is a twitter button to share the those individual video.

When you click on the twitter button, you will get a link like:
http://yoursite.com/index.html#video-1

So the link will point you to the bottom of the page.
However, I am trying to figure out the pseudo code and logic to point you to the bottom of the page and also rotate to the correct video.

At the moment, 
http://yoursite.com/index.html#video-1
http://yoursite.com/index.html#video-2
http://yoursite.com/index.html#video-3

will all point to #video-1

Comment: Which jQuery plugin for carousel are you using?

Comment: It is coded from scratch by a previous developer who has left. How can my code detect the link is from http://yoursite.com/index.html#video-2 and then show you video-2. I can't figure out the logic.

Comment: Without any code we can't help you. I assume within javascript you will have to rotate depending on click.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out.

Essentially, just do a string detection in the URL and that will solve the problem.

```
    // Check the URL for a given # anchor string
if(document.URL.indexOf("buying-a-car") != -1) {
    $("#YTvideo"+1).show();       
} else if(document.URL.indexOf("taking-a-holiday") != -1){
    $("#YTvideo"+2).show();      
} else if(document.URL.indexOf("moving-to-new-zealand") != -1){
    $("#YTvideo"+3).show();      
} else if(document.URL.indexOf("selling-your-house") != -1){
    $("#YTvideo"+4).show();      
} else{
    $("#YTvideo"+1).show();     
}
```